# "<br>" being changed to "&lt;br&gt;" even though I'm using html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am calling a helper method from a view to display some media.

index.html.erb

```
<%= media_display(:media => m[:media], :thumbnail => true).html_safe %>
```

application_helper.rb

```
def media_display p = {}
    (image_tag p[:media].author_picture) + "<br>"
end
```

HTML output

```
<img src="path_to_image" alt="Bartolo_normal">&lt;br&gt;
```

The image HTML works fine. Why is `<br>` not coming through as allowed HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
raw("<br>")
```